# Finding the number of subarrays with product less than the given integer k

Tags: java, sliding-window

I tried solving this question using sliding window technique but failed to get through the below test case: nums = [10,9,10,4,3,8,3,3,6,2,10,10,9,3] and k = 19.

```
class Solution {
    public int numSubarrayProductLessThanK(int[] nums, int k) {
        int count = 0;
        int j = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
         if(j <= nums.length){
            count += getCount(nums,j,k);
             j++;
         }
    }
        return count;
}
    
    public int getCount(int[] nums, int size, int k){
        int window_pro = 1;
        int count = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            window_pro *= nums[i];
        
        if(window_pro < k)
            count++;
        
        for(int i = size; i < nums.length; i++){
            window_pro = (window_pro * nums[i])/nums[i-size];
                if(window_pro < k)
                    count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

The above test case is supposed to give 18 as output i.e. there are 18 subarrays each of whose product is less than **19**. But with my code above, the output is 23. It passed 24 test cases before failing at this one. Please help!

Comment: Do you know the 18 correct subarrays? Can you list them as example? Did you output those which your program counts? Can you list them as debug info?

Comment: Yeah sure! [10],[9],[10],[4],[3],[8],[3],[3],[6],[2],[10],[10],[9],[3], [4,3],[3,3],[3,6],[6,2].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide both lists - and state which is which... At a guess the list you have given is the wrong one produced by your code, because it e.g. does not contain [10, 4,3] or others with three or more entries. And that might be the answer. Let me know please.